# How do you use jquery to toggle an element between display:none and display:flex

Tags: jquery, css

I have a very simple menu, but on the very last level only I need it to overflow into a second column if there are more than 4 items. This should be simple with flex but because I am using display:none to hide the whole menu it breaks the flex.

Somehow I think I may need to use jquery to change the flex for the clicked element if its in the final level but I am killing myself trying to figure out how to do it.

Maybe there is an easier way to achieve this or am I at least thinking in the right direction?

Help?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul li').click(function(ev) {
        $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle()
        .end().siblings().find('ul').hide();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```css
.dc-siteSimpleMenu {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  top: 0px;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #979797;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu-start {
  position: fixed;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu-start>li>a {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
}
/* I want to use flex like this for the component that has been clicked

.dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2{
  height:55px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dc-siteSimpleMenu">
  <ul class="dc-siteSimpleMenu-start">
    <li><a href='#'>menu</a>
      <ul class="dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-0">
        <li><a href='#'>Item 1</a>
          <ul class="dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-1">
            <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1</a>
              <ul class="dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2">
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-3</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-4</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-5</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-6</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-7</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>Item 1-2</a>
              <ul class="dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2">
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-2-2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I put together a fiddle to show the issue https://jsfiddle.net/duncanchard/3gvo02tk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do ti like this:

```
$('.dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-1 a').click(function(ev) { 
$('ul .dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2').hide(); // in order to hide if shown before
  $(this).next('ul .dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2').css({
   'display' : 'flex',
   'flex-direction' : 'column',
   'flex-wrap' : 'wrap',
   'height' : '55px'
});; 
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will apply CSS on click.

And add class:

```
ul.dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2  li {
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

`flex-basis: 25%;` will break it at every 4th item .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul li').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).find('>ul').slideToggle()
      .end().siblings().find('ul').hide();

     
    ev.stopPropagation();
  });
});

$('.dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-1 a').click(function(ev) { 
$('ul .dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2').hide();
  $(this).next('ul .dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2').css({
   'display' : 'flex',
   'flex-direction' : 'column',
   'flex-wrap' : 'wrap',
   'height' : '55px'
});; 
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.dc-siteSimpleMenu {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  top: 0px;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #979797;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu-start {
  position: fixed;
}

.dc-siteSimpleMenu-start>li>a {
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
}


/*I want to use flex like this for the component that has been clicked

.dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2 {
  height: 55px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
*/

ul.dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2  li {
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dc-siteSimpleMenu">
  <ul class="dc-siteSimpleMenu-start">
    <li><a href='#'>menu</a>
      <ul class="dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-0">
        <li><a href='#'>Item 1</a>
          <ul class="dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-1">
            <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1</a>
              <ul class="dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2">
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-3</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-4</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-5</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-6</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-1-7</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>Item 1-2</a>
              <ul class="dc-siteSimpleMenu-lvl-2">
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Item 1-2-2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you could add an active class to your css file.

```
.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul ul{
    display: none;
}
.dc-siteSimpleMenu ul ul.active{
    display: flex;
}
```

Then in your javascript file in your click handler function you can remove active class from all ul's and add one to the current clicked element. Hope this explains, leave a comment if the answer doesn't explain good enough.